# Mysql generate multiples connections on multiple ports on windows server 2012

Tags: mysql, windows-server-2012, apache2

I have a detail in my server, if run a command netstat it show me this. Is normal?

```
TCP    127.0.0.1:53898        127.0.0.1:3306         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:53899        127.0.0.1:3306         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:53900        127.0.0.1:3306         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:53901        127.0.0.1:3306         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:53902        127.0.0.1:3306         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:53903        127.0.0.1:3306         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:53904        127.0.0.1:3306         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:53905        127.0.0.1:3306         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:53906        127.0.0.1:3306         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:53907        127.0.0.1:3306         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:53909        127.0.0.1:3306         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:53910        127.0.0.1:3306         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:53911        127.0.0.1:3306         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:53912        127.0.0.1:3306         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:53913        127.0.0.1:3306         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:53914        127.0.0.1:3306         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:53916        127.0.0.1:3306         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:53917        127.0.0.1:3306         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:53918        127.0.0.1:3306         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:53919        127.0.0.1:3306         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:53920        127.0.0.1:3306         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:53921        127.0.0.1:3306         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:53923        127.0.0.1:3306         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:53924        127.0.0.1:3306         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:53925        127.0.0.1:3306         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:53926        127.0.0.1:3306         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:53927        127.0.0.1:3306         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:53928        127.0.0.1:3306         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:53929        127.0.0.1:3306         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:53930        127.0.0.1:3306         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:53931        127.0.0.1:3306         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:53932        127.0.0.1:3306         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:53933        127.0.0.1:3306         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:53934        127.0.0.1:3306         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:53935        127.0.0.1:3306         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:53936        127.0.0.1:3306         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:53937        127.0.0.1:3306         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:53938        127.0.0.1:3306         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:53939        127.0.0.1:3306         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:53940        127.0.0.1:3306         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:53941        127.0.0.1:3306         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:53942        127.0.0.1:3306         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:53943        127.0.0.1:3306         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:53944        127.0.0.1:3306         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:53945        127.0.0.1:3306         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:53946        127.0.0.1:3306         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:53947        127.0.0.1:3306         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:53948        127.0.0.1:3306         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:53949        127.0.0.1:3306         TIME_WAIT       0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connections have different source ports, but the same destination port, `127.0.0.1:3306`. It's impossible for two TCP connections to have the same source and destination IP/port combination, therefor different ports in the source are needed, as the IP addresses and destination port are fixed.

State `TIME_WAIT` means that the connection is closed, but the connection info is still kept for a few seconds in case packets arrive later. This is not necessary for the localhost address, but that's the way the TCP/IP stack works.

You probably have a MySql client application on the same server, maybe some web application. Unless you use connection pooling, each request to a web page will open a new connection to the MySql server and close it after the request is done. So depending on the number of page hits you have, a large number of connections in state `TIME_WAIT` is to be expected.